# Возможен ли доступ к регистрам RTC-BACKUP через структуру битовых полей?

Tags: c, stm32, embedded

В МК STM32L0x1 есть несколько 32-битных backup регистров, доступ к которым возможен через MMIO:

```
// Доступ к регистру BKP0 через базовый адрес: RTC->BKP0R
uint32_t tmp = (uint32_t)&(RTC->BKP0R) + RTC_BKP_DR0;
// Запись в регистр BKP0 значения 42
*(volatile uint32_t *)tmp = 42;
// Чтение из регистра BKP0
uint32_t value = *(volatile uint32_t *)tmp;
```

Мне бы хотелось иметь доступ к данным регистрам через битовые поля структуры, которые отображаются непосредственно на область памяти, в которой эти регистры размещены:

```c
    // Объединение, которое будет отображаться в память
    typedef union
    {
       uint32_t value;

       struct
       {
         uint32_t flag_0   : 1;
         uint32_t flag_1   : 1;
         uint32_t err_cnt  : 4;
         uint32_t interval : 7;

       } bits;
    } bkp_data_t;

    // Экземпляр отображения битового поля на регистр BKP0
    bkp_data_t* bkp_data = (bkp_data_t*)((uint32_t)&RTC->BKP0R + RTC_BKP_DR0);

    // Функция установки битового поля
    void set_flag_0(bool value)
    {
       critical_enter();
       bkp_data->bits.flag_0 = value;
       critical_exit();
    }

    // Функция чтения битового поля
    bool get_flag_0(void)
    {
       bool ret = false;

       critical_enter();
       ret =  bkp_data->bits.flag_0;
       critical_exit();
       return ret;
    }
```

Такой подход является работоспособным при отображении битовых полей на произвольную область памяти в RAM для неатомарного доступа к отдельным битам. Но насколько жизнеспособно такое отображение в случае BACKUP регистров?

Comment: Type puning -- нехорошо, даже в RAM. А чем вам мешают **явные** битовые операции?

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов, type puning -- это про другое. Встраиваемость системы тут не при чём.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов, вы о чём-то тогда странном. Как может быть компилятор эффективнее битовых масок? Нет, я понимаю, что можно огород нагородить, но при стандартном написании в одном случае неявно, в другом явно будут сделаны одни и те же операции. Битовые маски — это качественно разложенные грабли. А type puning на них — грабли в квадрате.

Comment: @AlexF bit banding, насколько я знаю, позволяет получать атомарный доступ к отдельным битам, но не к  битовым полям. Поправьте, если ошибаюсь.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов, про поразрядный доступ к регистрам, если вы о доступе напрямую, то вообще чушь получается. Компилятор ничего не знает об особенностях шины, для которой будет осуществлена транзакция. Более того, для большинства шин невыровненные транзакции — прямой вызов Bus master abort.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов, и как это противоречит тому, о чём я говорю?

Comment: @0andriy Вы правы, доступ к невыровненным данным в архитектуре ARMv6M вызовет исключение Bus Fault. Но это не имеет каких-то последствий при доступе к регистрам периферии, которые изначально выровнены на границу слова. Таким образом, отображение битового поля размером в 1 машинное слово на регистр периферии того же размера не вызовет данное исключение.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов, и с 8051, и с 8080, и с Z80, сталкивался, они все 8-битные, ну ОК, Z80 - 8/16, если внутрь смотреть. Особенно у Z80 ISA развесистая, но там нет битового обращения с портами, только с регистровым файлом самого процессора или памяти. Я совершенно упустил момент, были ли в семействе контролеры, позволяющие MMIO организовать, но это совсем уже к делу не имеет отношения.